# JSON Transform in Spring Integration and dynamically setting file pattern which is coming in JSON Tag "filePattern"

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

[i have refered this answer and tried to pass dynamic file pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295806/dynamically-provide-directory-and-file-name-to-ftp-outbound-gateway)

> applicationContext to set environment variables and and calling SI Gateway

```
public class TestSpringIntegration {
public TestSpringIntegration() {
    super();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TestSpringIntegration testSpringIntegration = new TestSpringIntegration();
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SI-filters_files.xml");

    setEnvironment(context);
//  context.refresh();


    ServiceGateway gateway =
     context.getBean("inboundGateway",ServiceGateway.class);


}

private static void setEnvironment(final ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
    String name = "server_text1";
    final StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("filename.pattern", "'" + name + "'");
    // props.setProperty("ftp.local.dir", ftpMetaData.getLocalDirectory());

    final PropertiesPropertySource pps = new PropertiesPropertySource("ftpprops", props);
    env.getPropertySources().addLast(pps);
    ctx.setEnvironment(env);
}
}
```

> this is my SI-filters_files.xml
>   I have set environment properties above to get dynamic filePattern in file adapter.

```
<int:channel id="requestChannel" />
<int:channel id="deadLetterChannel" />
<int:channel id="outboundChannel" />

<int:gateway id="inboundGateway" service-interface="test.ServiceGateway"
    default-request-channel="requestChannel" default-reply-timeout="5000" />



<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn"
    directory="file://<IP_ADDRESS>/sharedLocation/" filename-pattern="${filename.pattern}"
    channel="requestChannel" auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="requestChannel"
    output-channel="outboundChannel" ref="handler" />

<bean id="handler" class="test.FileHandler" />

<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundChannel"
    directory="file://E:/" />
```

Below is the exception I am getting:

> 2016-11-30 10:17:59 INFO  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:581 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@dcf3e99: startup date [Wed Nov 30 10:17:59 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>   2016-11-30 10:17:59 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [SI-filters_files.xml]
>   2016-11-30 10:17:59 INFO  PropertiesFactoryBean:172 - Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/F1038/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
>   2016-11-30 10:17:59 INFO  IntegrationRegistrar:330 - No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
>   2016-11-30 10:17:59 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:818 - Overriding bean definition for bean 'outboundChannel' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
>   2016-11-30 10:17:59 WARN  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:549 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileListFilterFactoryBean#0' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'filename.pattern' in string value "${filename.pattern}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'filename.pattern' in string value "${filename.pattern}"
>   Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileListFilterFactoryBean#0' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'filename.pattern' in string value "${filename.pattern}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'filename.pattern' in string value "${filename.pattern}"
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:223)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:180)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:152)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>       at test.TestSpringIntegration.main(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'filename.pattern' in string value "${filename.pattern}"
>       at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
>       at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
>       at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:219)
>       at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:193)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:209)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:220)

Answer (score 0):

With that constructor, the context is refreshed automatically, before you added the property source.

Use the no-arg constructor, pass the XML into `setConfigLocations`, set up your property source; call `context.refresh()`.

Or, use this constructor:

```
public ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String[] configLocations, boolean refresh)
```

See the [dynamic-ftp-sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/ftp/DynamicFtpChannelResolver.java#L95) for an example.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, it is customary here to mark the answer as accepted (click the tick/check mark under the voting buttons to the left of the answer. It will help other users when searching for answers.

Comment: Hi Gary.. I was trying to do so. But I have 6 points yet. After 15 points it will get displayed automatically. My feedback +1 has already been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

applicationContext.xml

```
    ServiceGateway gateway = context.getBean("inboundGateway", ServiceGateway.class);
    String json = " {\"vesselVisitCode\": \"XV213443\", \"fileName\": \"server_text1.txt\",\"originalFilename\": \"server.txt\" }";
    String json1 = "{\"fileName\": \"server_text1.txt\"}";
    gateway.post(json1);
```

> Earlier I had done it like (a work around i guess )...

```
<context:property-placeholder />

<context:component-scan base-package="test"></context:component-scan>

<int:channel id="requestChannel" />
<int:channel id="deadLetterChannel" />
<int:channel id="outboundChannel" />

<int:gateway id="inboundGateway" service-interface="test.ServiceGateway"
    default-request-channel="requestChannel" default-reply-timeout="5000" />

<int:splitter input-channel="requestChannel"
    output-channel="processingChannel" />


<int:transformer id="tx" input-channel="processingChannel" 
    ref="jsonHandler" method="jsonBreak" output-channel="loggingChannel" />

<int:channel id="loggingChannel" />

<int:channel id="processingChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor" />
</int:channel>

<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="5" />

<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" 
    directory="file://170.197.229.119/ftp/" channel="loggingChannel" >
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="100"/>

</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

```
<bean id="jsonHandler" class="test.JSONHandler" />
<bean id="handler" class="test.SelectMessage" />

<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundChannel"
    directory="file://E:/" />
```

> JSONHandler.java

```
public class JSONHandler {
@Autowired
SelectMessage message;

public String jsonBreak(String json) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement element = gson.fromJson(json, JsonElement.class);
    JsonObject jsonObj = element.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonElement jsonElement = jsonObj.get("fileName");
    String asString = jsonElement.getAsString();
    message.setFileName(asString);

    System.out.println("in Handler----------------------------------" + json);

    return asString;
}
```

}

> SelectMessage.java

```
public class SelectMessage implements MessageSelector {
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;

private String fileName;

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public boolean accept(Message<?> message) {
    try {
        if (message.getPayload() instanceof File && ((File) message.getPayload()).getName().startsWith((getFileName()))) {
            System.out.println(" --------------------return file on true match --------------------");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @Gary Russell: I am new to Spring Integration. I have googled to stop file adapter poller after one time polling to directory. I found trigger and SI cron... please provide more on it... A Big Thanks!!